# How to buffer messages on signal hub and send them when the right client appears?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have two type of clients connecting my signalR server (ASP.NET Core). Some of them are senders, and some of them are receivers. I need to route messages from senders to the receivers, which is not a problem, but when there is no receivers, I need to somehow buffer messages and not lose them (probably the best is ConcurrentQueue in some kind of a singleton class) but when the first receiver connect, the message buffer needs to start dequeue. Which is the best approach for this?

I created singleton class that wraps arround ConcurrentQueue collection and I enqueue and dequeue messages there. Also I have a separate singleton class which persist collection of the receivers connectionIDs. And I implemented event in this second class that fires event when first receiver connects after the list of receivers was empty but maybe this is not a good approach, I don't know how to use id in Hub, because there is more than one instance of a signalR hub.
Second approach is to mark persistance class as controller and inject the ContextHub and message buffer in this class and dequeue buffer from there and directly send messages to the receivers???

Comment: How can I properly inject IHubContext and two other singleton classes to my Controller class?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to defer SignalR message sending by using something like a synchronized call in some IHostedService. Here is what I managed to achieve so far.

- Your approach that consists in using a ConcurrentQueue that contains invokable Action delegates to handle the concurrent hub calls is the right one. As you mention, it has to be injected as a singleton.

So here the `Queues` class:

```
public class Queues {
    public ConcurrentQueue<Action<IHubContext<MyHub, IMyEvents>>> MessagesQueue { get; set; }
}
```

- Now we need to capture the `ConnectionId` of the caller so a call can get an answer later. `SendMessage` enqueue the necessary action delegate to perform a call against a hub instance as a parameter.

As an example `SendMessage` will trigger an answer back to the caller, and `BroadcastMessage` will send a message to all clients.

*Using a captured hub instance instead would lead to an exception here because the hub will be disposed, quickly. That's why it would be injected later in another class. Have a look on `SendMessage_BAD`*

Here is the `MyHub` class and the corresponding `IMyEvents` interface:

```
public interface IMyEvents {
    void ReceiveMessage(string myMessage);
}

public class MyHub : Hub<IMyEvents> {
    Queues queues;

    public MyHub(Queues queues) {
        this.queues = queues;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message) {
        var callerId = Context.ConnectionId;
        queues.MessagesQueue.Enqueue(hub => hub.Clients.Client(callerId).ReceiveMessage(message));
    }

    // This will crash
    public void SendMessage_BAD(string message) {
        this.callerId = Context.ConnectionId;
        queues.MessagesQueue.Enqueue(_ => this.Clients.Client(callerId).ReceiveMessage(message));
    }

    public void BroadcastMessage(string message) {
        queues.MessagesQueue.Enqueue(hub => hub.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(message));
    }
}
```

- Now, using a naive approach, this code will trigger the message sending a deferred way. (At work, a timer ensure a regular cadence, and the class is an `IHostedService` but it is does not appear here). This class has to be injected as a singleton.

Here the `DeferredMessageSender` class:

```
public class DeferredMessageSender {
    Queues queues;
    IHubContext<MyHub, IMyEvents> hub;

    public DeferredMessageSender(Queues queues, IHubContext<MyHub, IMyEvents> hub) {
        this.queues = queues;
        this.hub = hub;
    }

    public void GlobalSend() {
        while(queues.MessagesQueue.TryDequeue(out var evt)) {
            evt.Invoke(hub);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I know, that some of the clients did not receive the message, so I can retry later? I have message queueing on clients, but I have no idea, how to ensure delivering to them what they missed after reconnect. I cant find any resources, do you have any idea how to it?

Comment: This is tricky. We are using a workaround which consists in pushing every message we send in a rolling list with a timestamp1 (to limit the amount of buffered messages). When a client disconnects the first time, he gets the timestamp when it happens, then he tries to reconnect until it manages to do so. Then it send a "getmissedmessage(timestamp)", so the server fetches the messages before this timestamp from the rolling list, and resend them to that client only.