# Wait for a deferred value in a lambda before returning it in a function

Tags: c#, thread-synchronization

I have a function call (in a SignalR hub) that is supposed to return a `MyState` object.

The `MyState` object is not quite ready at the time it is needed by the caller and has to be processed first by some background process prior being eligible as being ready to be sent.

That's why I want the action that retrieves the state to be queued in a stack to be processed later. This is part of an existing framework.

I am not good at all with the synchronization methods of the .NET framework, and everything I looked for is in JavaScript. So I  would need a bit help to fill what is missing here:

```
public MyState GetState() {
    MyState state;
    // var waitMe = someObjectThatCanWait(); ?

    actions.Enqueue(sync => {

        // This lambda will be executed later by a function that processes the actions queue
        state = sync.GetSyncState());

        // waitMe.NowYouCanGo()  ?
    });

    // waitMe.Wait() ?
    return state;
}
```

---

> EDIT I have something that works. It is a bit obscure to me I wonder
>   whether this is ok.
>
> ```
> public MyState GetState() {
>     MyState state;
>     var waitMe = new Barrier(2);
>
>     actions.Enqueue(sync => {
>
>         // This lambda will be executed later by a function that processes the actions queue
>         state = sync.GetSyncState());
>
>         waitMe.SignalAndWait();
>     });
>
>     waitMe.SignalAndWait();
>     return state;
> }
> ```

---

> EDIT2 I have something more suitable since it does not block the lambda
>   and the function at the same time
>
> ```
> public MyState GetState() {
>     MyState state;
>     var waitMe = new ManualResetEventSlim();
>
>     actions.Enqueue(sync => {
>
>         // This lambda will be executed later by a function that processes the actions queue
>         state = sync.GetSyncState());
>
>         waitMe.Set();
>     });
>
>     waitMe.Wait(1500);
>     return state;
> }
> ```

Comment: Maybe you could use [WaitHandles](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/waithandles.html)?

Comment: Interresting. Thank you ! I am reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives?view=netframework-4.8) as well, wondering which one is the better for my use. Some are OS wide, other domain wide, I am looking for the lightest waithandle possible.

Comment: I would need to re-read it myself to refresh the memory, but I think Mutex are OS wide, while I've been using ManualResetEvent to synchronize threads inside a single app.

Comment: Barrier seems to do the job. I really cannot guess if it is used the right way or not too overkill.

Comment: I think that `SignalAndWait()` inside your queue can block the execution in some scenarious when using barrier, while from what you explained you don't want to block the execution there, just on returning of the state.

Comment: You're right, I am doubtful about Barrier. Let's try a ManualResetEventSlim instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of similar workflow using [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<(string Data, TaskCompletionSource<string> Tcs)> Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<(string Data, TaskCompletionSource<string> Tcs)>();

    static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue(cts.Token), cts.Token);
        ListenForTasks().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    private static async Task ListenForTasks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "q")
            {
                break;
            }

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            Queue.Enqueue((input, tcs));

            Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
            var result = await tcs.Task;
            Console.WriteLine($"waited: {result}");
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessQueue(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (!Queue.TryDequeue(out var item))
            {
                continue;
            }

            //emulate work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"processed {item.Data}");
            item.Tcs.SetResult(item.Data + "_PROCESSED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample, unfortunately it does not quite match my scenario. The queue processing is outside.

Comment: @Larry why? Add task to the queue and wait for completion isn't your scenario?

Comment: Not quite : I am just waiting this action to be finished, not the while queue. By the way, the queue involved is part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735378/how-to-buffer-messages-on-signal-hub-and-send-them-when-the-right-client-appears)