# How to handle client view synchronization with signal r when a client gets offline for a short period of time and some messages are lost?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using SignalR in my web api to provide real-time functionality to my client apps (mobile and web). Everything works ok but there is something that worries me a bit:

The clients get updated when different things happen in the backend. For example, when one of the clients does a CRUD operation on a resource that will be notified by SignalR. But, what happens when something happens on the client, let's say the mobile app, and the device data connection is dropped?.

It could happen that another client has done any action over a resource and when SignalR broadcasts the message it doesn't arrive to that client. So, that client will have an old view sate.

As I have read, it seems that there's no way to know if a meesage has been sent and received ok by all the clients. So, beside checking the network state and doing a full reload of the resource list when this happens is there any way to be sure message synchronization has been accomplished correctly on all the clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've suggested, ASP NET Core SignalR places the responsibility on the application for managing message buffering if that's required.

If an eventually consistent view is an issue (because order of operations is important, for example) and the full reload proves to be an expensive operation, you could manage some persistent queue of message events as far back as it makes sense to do so (until a full reload would be preferable) and take a page from message buses and event sourcing, with an onus on the client in a "dumb broker/smart consumer"-style approach.

It's not an exact match of your case, but credit where credit is due, there's a well thought out example of handling queuing up SignalR events here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984518/13374279 You'd have to adapt that some and give a numerical order to the queued events.

The initial state load and any subsequent events could have an aggregate version attached to them; at any time that the client receives an event from SignalR, it can compare its currently known state against what was received and determine whether it has missed events, be it from a disconnection or a delay in the hub connection starting up after the initial fetch; if the client's version is out of date and within the depth of your queue, you can issue a request to the server to replay the events out to that connection to bring the client back up to sync.

Some reading into immediate consistency vs eventual consistency may be helpful to come up with a plan. Hope this helps!